# Formerly working Matlab Compiler-based DLL suddenly cannot initialize

Tags: delphi, matlab-compiler

**Update**: It turned out that there was something with installing Delphi 10.4 CE that broke my app (thanks, DelphiCoder!); specifically, it was something in the Windows Registry that was broken. After using ProcessMonitor to ensure no Delphi 10.4 (aka 21.0) was being invoked, I ended up cleaning out the registry of all 10.4 references, rebuilding completely (not clear if this was needed or not), and lo and behold, it works again! I'm adding this update in case someone in a similar situation finds this question - remember to back up your registry first and be careful!

**Original Post**: I created several DLLs with Matlab Compiler 10 years ago, with C wrappers, to make them available with Delphi. Once I got them working, they always worked - until today! The code in the C wrapper initialization function in question is in the code box below; the "Could not initialize library" is printed to the console when I run my Delphi app.

```
mclmcrInitialize();
if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize application\n");
}
if (!libMyDllInitialize()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize library\n");
}
```

The problem is that this has never happened before, over all the probably 10 years since we first wrote these! My machine has the correct version of the 32-bit 2021a MCR installed, as it has for several years; I've installed this on numerous machines from Windows XP up to Windows 10, The DLLs were last built 5 - 7 years ago; anyway, I don't have access to the Matlab compiler anymore. The only thing that has changed is my app, but not anywhere near where this DLL initialization code is called; also, when the problem first happened, my app was working, then didn't -without any changes. Finally, I went back a few days and rebuilt my app, and it still fails.

So I am really stuck, and need some advanced help in debugging DLL startup issues on Windows. I tried looking in the Windows Event Logger, but nothing appears to show up there. Logs to check? A setting in the Registry that somehow got hosed? Wrong phase of the moon? How does one debug loading/initializing a formerly working DLL when forced to treat it as a black box? Help!

Comment: I can't see a specific answerable question here. However, relying on DLLs that you can't modify is problem waiting to happen.

Comment: That source code is bogus anyway - there are specific OS error codes of what could have happened. Stripping that down into "yes" and "no" is the first mistake. Find out why the actual error being returned.

Comment: You're not forced to treat it as a black box.  `libMyDllInitialize` does something.  You haven't shown us what that is.  In there must be WinAPI calls where you are not checking return error codes.  The first thing to do is to implement error handling on all WinAPI calls that generate them.  Once you have that error information you can [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Just a guess: Did you change the used Delphi version?

Comment: I agree with the first three comments, but unfortunately, it sort of is what it is at the moment; my client is not inclined to pursue recompiling the DLLs. Your comments do give me additional ammo if I cannot resolve this, so you've provided value there - thanks!

Comment: @DelphiCoder - thanks! You may be on to something. I've been using Delphi 10.2.3 only for this (paying) project, but recently installed the 10.4 Community Edition for a hobby project. I am not exactly sure whether this installation was in between "working" and "broken" behavior, but it feels highly likely that it was indeed! I actually thought of this myself, though I didn't expect it was likely, so I tried uninstalling 10.4 and the problem persists. I wouldn't have thought installing a different version would break a project using a prior version. Do you know something I don't?

Comment: That was not what I had in mind. I suspected you maybe switched from a pre Unicode version to something more current.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How does one debug loading/initializing a formerly working DLL [...]?

I think there is no definitive answer to your question.

This is how we have gone about debugging the loading/initializing of DLLs and applications and may help you:

- We regularly work with systems where we have no source code for the DLLs (and often we don't have any source code for the applications either). We experience DLL conflicts quite regularly. When testing why applications don't start as expected we have found the use of [Sysinternal's Process Monitor by Mark Russinovich](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) invaluable.

  This will show you system level activity. You can filter for your process and then you will see all file, registry, thread and network activity (although thread and network are quite limited). If the DLL has dependencies then the system tries to find those and so you will be able to discover all dependent DLLs and COM interfaces (by seeing the registry lookups for that interface) that it's looking for. *Process Monitor* will show if the resource is not found or if access is denied.
- Slightly more difficult to discover is if one of the dependencies exists but the export table has changed (so the functions have different signatures or export ordinals). There are ways to check that (by looking at the export and import tables) but generally (if you have access to a working environment) it's enough to check the filesize, timestamp (and the [VERSIONINFO resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) if there is one) between DLLs.

Comment: (Wasn't me but) Your first sentence is wonky - sure it doesn't need more punctuation (quotation or question marks)? Also you could at least [link to Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) right away - don't let every reader repeat all the work ("_search for_") - do it once for everyone.

Comment: @AmigoJack - thanks for your comment, I have reworded slightly and included the link.  Hopefully the English is clearer now ... ?

Comment: See [my edit remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71253695/revisions) and please start using formattings. Maybe suggest tools and link to them (e.g. viewing a VERSIONINFO resource via [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and viewing DLL exports via [NirSoft's DLL Export Viewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html)).

Comment: @AmigoJack thanks for your comments.  Personally I find the bullets detract from the natural reading of the answer, mainly because they're on a paragraph rather than a punch point.  Of course I accept that's a matter of personal preference!

Comment: The first sentence of your answer neatly captures the problem with the answer. Unfortunately, answering questions that don't fit here tends to result in down votes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for the feedback.  The techniques I have outlined have been used to solve situations that _appear to be_ exactly like the situation described.  Of course there's not enough detail to know exactly what's going on.  Rather than thinking about whether the questions fits the parameters I understand for this channel I have offered information to someone that _might_ help them solve a problem that could be critical for them.  As someone who has to solve problems under constraints I can't change (like closed source) I know I appreciate help when it's offered.

Comment: @RobLambden Your response is sort of exactly what I was hoping for. Of course, my "question" was very open-ended, and I can't argue with David Hefferman, but I was getting desperate, and really was looking for advice. Thanks!